# Php, print value of constant (define)

Tags: php, variables

The following code returns 'MY_URL' rather that the value of the constant.  How can I print out the value of the MY_URL pleasE?

```
define('MY_URL','https://www.url.com');
print MY_URL
```

Thanks,

Comment: Your code should work, are you absolutely sure what you posted is the exact code you are using?

Comment: The code you have pasted in the question echos "https :// www.url.com" which implies it's not the code you're actually using.

Comment: [No it doesn't](http://codepad.org/6mzZVB0G)... Are you sure that is the exact code you tested?

Comment: Your code works for me: http://codepad.org/4ewgPWYK

Comment: Maybe add a semi-colon after the print-statement? Or perhaps changing it to `echo` instaed of print (just to try something)? ... What version of php are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you sure?  [check your code here](http://writecodeonline.com/php/)

Comment: Sorry, my bad, was simply a typo.

Answer (score 0):

There's the [`constant()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function for retrieving the value of a previously defined constant. *Although*, your code - as posted - should also print the constant's value.

Double check if you haven't by accident [`defined()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php) the constant (as opposed to [`define()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)d).

This is a sad and hard to spot typo (that happens to me more than often):

```
defined('MY_URL', 'some-value');
print MY_URL;  // prints "MY_URL" and a notice
```

Answer (score -1):

you could try:

```
echo MY_URL;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: In this format there is exactly zero difference between the functionality of `print` and `echo`

Comment: yes. but i've added the ';' that he did not have.

Comment: If that was the problem, he would get a `Parse error` and nothing would be printed at all.

Comment: you are right! Could be some mis-configuration on the server that its not processing these kind of variables?

Comment: He stated on the answer he accepted (which didn't answer anything), that he had a typo.